# Changing the Sampling Rate in UBUNTU 12.04

Tags: sound, alsa

I have used POCKETSPHINX for speech recognition in my project. Pocketsphinx is recognizing words but as it works on a sample rate of 16000 Hz and our laptop takes input at 22050 Hz, output is not as efficient as we would like. So, please tell me the procedure of changing the sampling rate to 16000 Hz in Ubuntu 12.04. I am stuck at this point and need help. Any suggestions from your side regarding this issue are welcome.

For changing the sampling rate, I have tried to modify `pulse.conf`, `alsa.conf` in UBUNTU 12.04. I have also tried to add `.asoundrc` file. But nothing has worked. So, I want to know the *exact procedure of changing the sampling rate* to 16000 Hz in UBUNTU 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

**pocketsphinx_continuous -adcdev hw:1**  (this wont work in your case, obviously swap the "1" for the card index you want - derived from **aplay -l** or **alsamixer, then press F6** or w/e )

Giving an error like:

```
Available samping rate 44100 is too far from requested 16000
FATAL_ERROR: "continuous.c", line 246: Failed to open audio device
```

However:

**pocketsphinx_continuous -adcdev plughw:1**  (This will silently handle your conversion)

Hope it helps (if a little late)

Answer (score 0):

If the hardware supports 16 kHz, it will use this rate automatically.

If the hardware does not support 16 kHz, nothing you do in software can change this.